# Linux Script Set Permission Function

Tags: linux, sh

I wrote a simple script to set permissions for a file or folder for some embedded Linux devices as part of a larger setup script.

This method would be called on less than 20 files and folders. It seems to work correctly.  For the Linux OS, the stat command is not available. Please let me know if anyone notices any issue or knows of a better way to set and check file and folder permissions.

Thanks.

```
# Runs 'chmod' command to set folder or file permissions.
# Uses 'find' command with permission parameter to verify
# the file or folder exists with the permissions that 
# were set.
#  Param1 = NumericPermission. Param2 = File/Folder path.
set_permissions()
{
local text
chmod $1 $2 
text="$(find $2 -maxdepth 0 -perm $1)"
if [ -e $2 ]; then    
    if [ -n "$( echo $text | grep $2)" ]; then
        PermissionResult=$PASSED
        echo "Permissions set."
    else
        PermissionResult=$FAILED        
        printf " Permissions for '$2' not correctly set.\n" >> $SETUP_LOG 
    fi
else
    printf " Path not found for '$2'.\n" >> $SETUP_LOG
fi
}

#Usage:
local file='/home/testfile'
printf "test file" > $file 
set_permissions 777 $file
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 3):

It's worth a trip through Shellcheck, as there are some standard mistakes here, notably failing to quote strings such as `"$1"` or `"$PASSED"` - though the latter is probably a mistake, since `PASSED` is never assigned (I recommend `set -u` to catch use of undefined variables).

It seems silly to interpolate strings into the format string for `printf` (and it's risky, if those strings might contain `%` or `\`).  The obvious solution is to use `%s` for the argument, though you could instead interpolate and use `echo` or `printf '%s\n'`.

Also, is `"$2"` expected to expand to a filename or to a regular expression?  It's unlikely to be a good argument to both `find` and `grep` simultaneously.

Given that we actually only care whether `find` produced some output or not, then we could easily just grep for a non-empty line:

```
    if find "$2" -maxdepth 0 -perm "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q .
    then
        echo "Permissions set."
        return 0
    else
        printf " Permissions for '%s' not correctly set.\n" "$2" |
            tee -a "$SETUP_LOG" >&2
        return 1
    fi
```

It's not clear what this script aims to provide that's not provided by plain `chmod`, which will leave the file untouched if permissions are already as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I added quotes around the param. strings and added the %s format for printf.  I know about making recursive calls (chmod -R) but the files and folders are not all in the same location.

Comment: Also, this will only be used where the second string argument is always the file path, so no regular expressions are used.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `-maxdepth 0` - I think `find` is overkill for a simple `stat` test.  And none of your path names will ever contain any of `[]\?*.` or other regex characters?  You're lucky - on my systems, `.` at least occurs quite frequently in filenames.  Perhaps you wanted `grep -F`, but that still has chance of false positive.

Comment: Yeah I wish I could use stat but this is on devices with embedded Linux with very limited versions of Linux; stat is not available.

Comment: No, none of the files will ever contain any invalid characters. This is part of a setup script for devices that my team configures and we control the entire process.

Comment: I added -F to grep, thanks. I don't know if this will ever cause a false positive, but on the device I am testing the find method shown only returns one string, which is the full path of the file or folder.  Its not perfect but we don't have similarly named files for this case, so I think it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. verify that the file indeed exists
2. retrieve the current permissions and compare them to the expected value

The output of the Linux `find` command can be customized. Thus:

```
find /path/to/file -printf "%m\n"
```

will return the octal permissions for a given file eg 644 or 755 etc.
The exit code will be != 0 if the file doesn't exist.

Likewise, you could return with an **exit code** > 0 if the check does not succeed. This will make it possible for any caller routine (or the rest of your installation script) to determine the outcome of the command and behave accordingly.

Also, to **log** the output of your script, you could run something like this at the start of your script:

```
exec &> >(tee -a "$SETUP_LOG")  # for stdout and stderr
```

so that there is no need to pipe or tee in every command. [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145654/190343)

Google Linux file redirection for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately our versions of LInux find do not support the -printf option for find.  We are already using the &> operator to log all activity and errors, but we have another app. that reads and parses specific log entries after setup, so we need another log file that has less info with a specific format.

Comment: Can you mention the version of Linux you're using for your embedded device? Unless it's proprietary you can probably build your own customized image but I understand this may be a hassle.

Comment: ~ $>uname -a
Linux [manufacturer redacted]_2070LX 2.6.39 #2 PREEMPT Mon Aug 1 15:51:52 CDT 2016 ppc GNU/Linux
~ $>

Comment: There are 4 different Linux versions depending on the manufacturer. The Linux distros are very lightweight.

Comment: Customized versions of Linux would likely void the warranties. We discussed this a while back and opted not to make our own.

Comment: I'm guessing yours is a Busybox-derived Linux, which does indeed provide a Linux kernel, but not the userland utilities many users expect when they hear "Linux". Perhaps going forward it would make sense to specifically mention that you can't rely on nonstandard GNU `find`, GNU `grep` etc behaviors which are otherwise nearly always available and installed by default in Linux distros.